# How to make top edges alone curve in d3.js

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

I'am trying to make top right and top left as curved I try to use ry but it making 4 side curve.

[image]

Comment: Post the code you use that is making a 4 sided curve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a rounded bar, replace `<rect>` with `<path>`, and set the path's `d` attribute to the path returned by `topRoundedRectPath`:

```js
const topRoundedRectPath = (x, y, width, height, radius) => {
  return `M ${x},${y + height} V ${y + radius} 
    Q ${x},${y}, ${x + radius},${y} H ${x + width - radius} 
    Q ${x + width},${y} ${x + width},${y + radius} V ${y + height} Z`
}


const rectX = 10;
const rectY = 10;
const rectW = 30;
const rectH = 100;
const cornerRadius = 12;

d3.select('#first')
  .append('rect')
  .attr('x', rectX)
  .attr('y', rectY)
  .attr('width', rectW)
  .attr('height', rectH);

d3.select('#second')
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', topRoundedRectPath(rectX, rectY, rectW, rectH, cornerRadius));
```

```css
svg {
  width: 100px; 
  height: 120px;
}

rect, path {
  fill: blue;
  stroke: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg id="first">
</svg>

<svg id="second">
</svg>
```

Comment: It would be kinda cool to do something like `.attr('toproundedrect', true)` or something but I guess part of the beauty is in the exposed mechanics :)

Comment: @RobinMackenzie Definitely :) Standard CSS has `border-top-left-radius`, `border-top-right-radius` and so on, but SVG does not recognise those styles